# Newtonsoft.JSON v9.01 + FileNotFoundException (.NET Core Class library)

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-core

(VS2015 Update 3 + Patch)

I have a plain .NET console application (.NET 4.6) and reference a .NET core class library that targets NetStandard v1.3.
The class library has a reference to Newtonsoft.JSON.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },
  "buildOptions": { "platform": "anycpu" },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

The referenced NewtonSoft.JSON package is deployed here:

> C:\Users\UserAccount\.nuget\packages\Newtonsoft.Json\9.0.1

The Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in DotNetConsoleApplication.exe
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I guess the .net core lib would reference the dll from the netstandard1.0 folder.

[image]

Comment: How exactly do you reference that class library?

Comment: Add Reference-> I browsed to NetStandardv1.3 folder :
`C:\Users\UserAccount\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ASP.NETcoreApp\NetCore46ClassLibrary\bin\Debug\netstandard1.3\NetCore46ClassLibrary.dll`

Comment: @Legends I've got exact same problem, did you find out how to fix that ?

Comment: @nboisvert, no I did not explore it any further. In my case it works only if I add the  newtonsoft.json reference to the parent project which references the .net core class library and at the same time I remove the reference to newtonsoft.json in the core library. Then it will run, but this is very ugly and not recommended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved 31.07.2016**

Create a fresh plain .NET console app (not .NET Core) and a .NET Core  class library, without doing any referencing between them upfront.

**Scenario:**
 1. Console app based on .NET 4.6, which references a
 2. .Net Core Classlibrary (has a reference to Newtonsoft.JSON v9.01)

The .NET core class library is configured as follows (project.json):

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },
  "buildOptions": { "platform": "anycpu" },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Solution

**1.) Create a Nuget package from the .Net core class library project first.**

Open the command line as admin.
Go (cd) to the project folder of the .NET core class library project (.xproj).

Run the following command:

**dotnet pack**

[image]

The "pack" parameter will create a nuget package out of the .NET Core class library and copy the package to the debug/release folder, depends on your project configuration.

Copy the nuget package files to a **folder where you host your local nuget packages**.
I have copied them to:

> **C:\Users\Admin.nuget\packages\LocalPackages**\NetCore46ClassLibrary

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**2.) If you don't have a local Nuget feed,you have to create one first!**

The local Nuget folder (I named it "LocalPackages") will host your custom Nuget packages. The local Nuget Feed will point to "LocalPackages", which is the root folder for all local packages.

[image]

After you have created the local nuget feed and copied the nuget package of your .net core class library somewhere beneath the localPackages folder, you are ready to install your .net core class library nuget package.

**3.) Install the .NET Core library Nuget Package into the .NET console app**

you now have to open the Package Manager Console again. 
Choose Package Source: Local Packages (This is my local feed name, may be different).
And the default project should be your .NET console app.

[image]

Install your .net core class library nuget package into the console app, in my case:

```
install-package NetCore46ClassLibrary
```

That's it !

**My system**:
[image]

> dotnet --version
>   1.0.0-preview2-003121

Answer (score 4):

Creation of NuGet package is a solution but not the easiest one.

Microsoft finally admitted this is a problem and [will fix](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488) it, expectantly, in NuGet version 4.0.1, the first update to NuGet 4 after VS 2017 ships.

The cleanest workaround now is to add `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` to a legacy project. However [according to Rob Relyea](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488#issuecomment-277154422) MS will ignore this property after RTM so another workaround is `<PackageReference Update="PlaceholderToConvinceThisProjectToGetTransitivePackageReferenceFromProjectReferences"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the Newtonsoft assembly is 64 bit and your .Net Core project is 32 bit.  Also could be that you have multiple versions of Newtonsoft referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error recently, after including Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8 in a dotnet core console app.  The solution was to include the System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives dependancy to the project.json config.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives":  "4.0.10-*",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I encountered that bug in a .net standard 2.0 project, and I installed "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" in nuget, solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**As a workaround solution**, In visual studio 2017, you can modify the the NetStandard project .csproj as multi-target:

```
           <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.3;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

Rebuild the solution and the referenced dll (NewtonSoft.JSON) will be  copied to bin folder of the console project.

Have a look to my implementation in :[Workaround Solution](https://github.com/moh-hassan/nuget-dependencies-of-netstandard-library-bug)