# Dependencies not working when referencing .NET Standard 1.3 library from .NET 4.6.1 app

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, .net-standard

I have 2 projects in my solution. First is portable library targeting .NET Standard 1.3. This library has a dependency to Json.NET. Its project.json looks like following:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {}
  }
}
```

Library consists of just this simple class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestLibrary
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static string Foo() {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(42);
        }
    }
}
```

Second project is console application targeting full .NET 4.6.1 framework. This console app references library mentioned above. Code is following:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = TestLibrary.TestClass.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to build and run it, but calling `TestLibrary.TestClass.Foo()` results in following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"

There is no `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in my bin folder.

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (KB3165756) installed (14.0.25431.01, released on 09/14/2016) as well as .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2.

After spending too much time googling, I'm not sure whether a) I'm doing something wrong b) tooling doesn't support this scenario yet c) my Visual Studio installation is somehow broken.

EDIT: Here is [complete solution to reproduce](http://www.esentio.sk/temp/testdependencies.zip).

Comment: Are both ClassLibrary and Console app .NET Core application? I create both .NET Core ClassLibrary and Console app based on your description, I don't get any error message. If possible, I suggest you provide a sample project, I will run your app in my side to confirm whether there has any issue in your project or VS installation.

Comment: No, they are not .NET Core. Library is PCL targeting .NET Standard 1.3 and console app is targeting full .NET 4.6.1 framework. You can find sample project [here](http://www.esentio.sk/temp/testdependencies.zip) (cannot use GitHub right now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PCL library project manages packages with project.json file, but the common .NET Framework projects manage NuGet packages with packages.config.

I have tested if I install the Newtonsoft.Json package in your Console application manually, it could run successful. And if I reference the PCL library project using .NET Core Console app which also manage NuGet packages with project.json file, the solution could run successful too.

So in your situation, you need to install the NuGet packages that in PCL library project into your Console application manually.

Comment: Yes, when I install the dependencies to Console app, it works. And yes, I suspected that it has something to do with project.json/packages.config differencies. But the main question remains: is this scenario not supported by tooling? Will it be fixed in the future? I cannot find answer to that (maybe I'm just bad at googling it). Because my real world scenario is much more complex and it is annoying when I have to duplicate dependencies in all projects referencing standard library project. Anyway, I'll accept your answer, since it solves the problem.

Comment: I also don't find any news about whether this scenario is not supported or not. According to the document of NuGet, it mention that "For more information see the Code of Conduct FAQ or contact opencode@microsoft.com with any additional questions or comments". So I suggest you contact opencode@microsoft.com to submit this issue.

Comment: Accepted answer is out of date because project.json is no longer used for .net standard. They use a .csproj now.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to install dependencies of .NET Standard libraries manually.

Microsoft finally admitted this is a problem and [will fix](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488) it, expectantly, in NuGet version 4.0.1, the first update to NuGet 4 after VS 2017 ships.

The cleanest workaround now is to add `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` to a legacy (.NET 4.6.1. app in this case) project. However [according to Rob Relyea](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488#issuecomment-277154422) MS will ignore this property after RTM so another workaround is `<PackageReference Update="PlaceholderToConvinceThisProjectToGetTransitivePackageReferenceFromProjectReferences"/>`.

Another workaround is to pack a .NET Standard library into NuGet package like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38686264/5655977), but it is not the easiest way.