# I receive an error about the the package 'Newtonsoft.Json' under Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When I create new project in visual studio 2015 under .net core 1.0.0 (asp.net core) I receive an error about the the package 'Newtonsoft.Json'

[image: the message that I receive]

Comment: Did you restore your nuget packages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can open any `.csproj` files in your solution referencing `Newtonsoft.Json < v9.0.1`, bought up to v9.0.1 and delete bin folder from the xproj project.

Also you can take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349276/newtonsoft-json-v9-01-filenotfoundexception-net-core-class-library) for how to resolve some issues with `Newtonsoft.JSON v9.0.1` in .net core.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run the project before it finishes restoring?
If that's the case you could try to restore them manually: right-click the solution -> Restore NuGet packages.