# Traditional console app referencing NetStandard project throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I have 2 projects (VS 2017 RC)

- MyLib (NetStandard1.4) - references e.q. Newtonsoft.Json
- MyConsoleApp (normal, traditional console application, targetting .Net 4.6.1) - references MyLib project

After compilation I get:

**MyLib**

- bin\Debug\netstandard1.4\MyLib.dll
- bin\Debug\netstandard1.4\MyLib.pdb
- bin\Debug\netstandard1.4\MyLib.deps.json <-- it has info about referencing Newtonsoft.Json

**MyConsoleApp**

- bin\Debug\MyLib.dll
- bin\Debug\MyLib.pdb
- bin\Debug\MyConsoleApp.exe
- bin\Debug\MyConsoleApp.exe.config
- bin\Debug\MyConsoleApp.pdb

MyConosleApp output is missing Newtonsoft.Json. When I run it I get `FileNotFoundException` (Newtonsoft.Json.dll).

How do I make it work (without migrating MyConosleApp to net core)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on suggestions from Andrew Cahill I found this thread on GitHub:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488

It looks like it's a bug and they will fix it. The workaround is to copy-paste  the code below to your Traditional application `.csprj` file. (no need to modity the snippet)

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Legacy2CPSWorkaround" Version="1.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

It somehow encourages VS to fetch dependencies of all referenced projects.

Comment: error  : The attribute "Version" in element <PackageReference> is unrecognized.

Comment: Removed the Version attribute and the project loads and there is an unknown file reference in the project and the same FileNotFoundException as before

Answer (score 1):

Please see this previous similar stack overflow post: [Newtonsoft.JSON v9.01 + FileNotFoundException (.NET Core Class library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349276/newtonsoft-json-v9-01-filenotfoundexception-net-core-class-library)
I hope this may assist somewhat.